# Gps Device data not edable

Tags: node.js, gps

I am using BW08 device tracking and send data to own server and server written in node js. But device send data on my server as

```
    *
    aD 'T�8

    aD 'T�8

    *
    aD 'T�8.79.48.102: xx

    *
    xx   �
                �C��8���n�

    xx   �
                �C��8���n�
```

How to read data?
My NodeJS server code is here:
    ===========================================================================

```
var net = require('net');
var HOST = 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx';
var PORT = 17000;

// Create a server instance, and chain the listen function to it
// The function passed to net.createServer() becomes the event handler for the 'connection' event
// The sock object the callback function receives UNIQUE for each connection
net.createServer(function(sock) {
    sock.setEncoding('utf8');
    // We have a connection - a socket object is assigned to the connection automatically
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

    // Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('*');
        console.log(data.toString('ascii'))
        console.log(data.toString());
        console.log('*');
        console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
        // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server
        sock.write('You said "' + data + '"');
    });

    // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
    });
}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

Comment: Did you proof-read your question at all? Please correct your errors (hint: parts of the code are in normal text).